# Ways to create custom commands for a text based adventure game?

Tags: java, text, textinput

So I have to make a text based adventure game for my programming class and I have a basic working game at this point, but I'd like to use custom inputs for it as opposed to a prompt and input set up. E.g. (player types "go west" as opposed to the game asking: "what direction do you want to move?" And the player submits an option.) Does anyone know of a good way to do this? Similar to the old school kinds of text based adventure games.

Comment: You need to implement some sort of `String` parser. One thing that might be relevant is to parse from string to an `enum` value and handle it thereafter. The questions is really vague as no code is presented.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a "basic working game" entails? Is all you're doing moving about, if so is this the end goal? If so there are loads of feasible way to handle the input, but they won't be easy to use for "move the green marble to the right" or other kinds of statements.

Comment: The goal is to move around and get to the end room, kind of like a maze. At this point all I'm talking about is moving from room to room

Comment: Can you add your current input code? It's hard to figure what you might using to not just be able to remove the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If previously you had something like this:

```
System.out.println("Which way do you want to go");
String direction = input.readLine().toLowerCase();
if(direction.equals("w")) 
    goWest();
```

To account for more complex user input (like having the user type in "Go West") you can do

```
String command = input.readLine().toLowerCase();
String[] parts = command.split(" "); //split the command at each space, so we have an array of each word
if(parts.length == 2 && parts[0].equals("go")) //check if there are two words and if the first word is "go"
    go(parts[1]); //supply the second word (the direction) to a go() function

....

public void go(String direction) {
    if(direction.equals("w") || direction.equals("west")) 
        goWest();
    else if(direction.equals("e") || direction.equals("east"))
        goEast();
   //etc.
}
```